# Using an iFrame to embed a website

Tags: html

I am trying to embed a site using an iframe. The problem I am running into is that after I reduce the width of the window to a certain point, I end up with horizontal scrollbars (this happens on mobile devices as well). Is there a way to make the content inside reduce to a smaller width?

Comment: You can't control the contents of an iframe unless you directly change the website you are placing inside of the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep for a comment, but...

You cannot fix this problem. It is the same as having a browser window too small for the website and forcing horizontal scroll bars. The website you are trying to frame has a minimum size in its css and you cannot make it go smaller than that. Sorry.

You could just turn off scroll bars, but then you wouldn't be able to see to the right of the frame.  (add `scrolling="no"` to the frame attributes, so `<iframe src="http://www.url.com" scrolling="no"></iframe>`).